# Why isn't the page redirecting after submitting form?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

So I have a form that only has two text fields and a button. When user clicks on the button to submit, I have a handleSubmit function that does an axios post to the express file in the backend. It all works, except for the redirect, i console.log the data in the app.post in the express file and it's correctly showing the data, and it's also showing up in the database.

This is what the form looks like

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="col s12 row">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="input-field col s6">
                        <input
                            value={this.state.title}
                            type="text"
                            className="validate"
                            onChange={this.handleTitleChange} />
                        <label className="active">Title</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="input-field col s6">
                        <textarea
                            id="textarea1"
                            value={this.state.body}
                            className="materialize-textarea"
                            onChange={this.handleBodyChange} />
                        <label className="active">Title</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="input-field col s6">
                        <button className="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
                            <i className="material-icons right">send</i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

And here is the handleSubmit method

```
handleSubmit(event) {
        axios.post('/api/newBlog', this.state)
            .then(res => console.log(res));
    }
```

And lastly the router code

```
app.post('/api/newBlog', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body);
        const blogPost = new Blog(req.body);
        blogPost.save();
        res.redirect("/")
    });
```

Whenever I press submit button, it redirects me to the same page but with slight difference. The page to the new blog form is "http://localhost:3000/newblog", but after clicking submit, it redirects me to "http://localhost:3000/newblog?action=" .  Why is "?action=" showing up in the url, and why is it not redirecting to "/"? I have "/" defined in my react-router and i can get there if i manually type it in the url.

Comment: Try this to redirect by React after submit success :  `axios.post('/api/newBlog', this.state)
            .then((res) => { this.props.history.push("/") } );`

Comment: it worked, but only after the .then() statement @TruongDang

Comment: Yep, in nodejs `return res.status(200).json({  some_data})` then check on React if success then redirect `"/"` or handle false....

Answer (score 0):

> "Why is "?action=" showing up in the url, and why is it not
>   redirecting to "/"? I have "/" defined in my react-router and i can
>   get there if i manually type it in the url."

==> Because by default submit method is Get not Post.( if U don't set method='POST' in form tag).

When click submits button, will submit all value of the tags has attribute is the name. append in Url ( if method = get)

In your case `<button name='action' ...`
Url will be `youdomain?action=`

And you haven't set action it means default submit to current URL

if you want manual redirect you can use:  `event.preventDefault()` in `handleSubmit()` method
like this:

```
handleSubmit(){
event.preventDefault();
// call API here, redirect url...

}
```

Or add click event into the button and remove type='submit'

```
<button onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
```

Hope, It can help you